# SDL Tridion UI Using .Net master pages

Tags: tridion

I have a question about implementing the new UI within a .net website that is built using master pages.

Our solution uses .NET master pages.  Everything is configured as documented [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=UIU4SDLT2011SP1&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=SE_LoadingDefaultTBBs.xml&docid=task_SE985885JFJFJJ995954FKKDFKF2CBB&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_SE985885JFJFJJ995954FKKDFKF2CBB&url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=UIU4SDLT2011SP1&lang)) in that our master page is using the <--INIT_SITE_EDIT--> code at the end of the file to ensure the siteedit /i code is embedded correctly.  When we are browsing the website and switch over to the UI interface, the masterpage is actually opened (even though the correct content components are pulled in for editing)... but this makes it impossible for the users to republish the full page within the new UI.

Is there a simple way to fix this that i'm missing? I fear I'm going to have to do some manipulation of the code that is output by the default UI/siteedit code blocks to drop in the correct page tcm-id.

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Have no details right now, but our training environment is using Master Pages and Tridion UI - There were some challenges, but no real issues deploying it there. Try comparing the resulting HTML with a "standard" page?

Comment: Hey Nuno, Thanks, I know i need the page ID of the real page in the <-- PageSettings --> part.   I just don't see a ootb way to provide that to the masterpage from my normal .aspx page?  I'm surely missing something obvious here.

Comment: Have you tried removing the site edit TBB from the master page and have it inside the actual page?

Comment: yeah i tried that, it fails because the Page settings tags are then put in the aspx page, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Put that inside a content placeholder, and load it from the master page. Remember, all that UI cares about is the end HTML of the rendered page

Comment: This is what I have and it is working with master pages, I have the siteedit init tag "<!-- SITE_EDIT_INIT -->" in one of the placeholder right above the body tag..  It is generating the following script tag when I published the page http://<cmsname>>/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js with id="tridion.siteedit".. I believe this is key for UI to work.  Above the script tag it also has the Page Settings JSON. On my page I have the SiteEdit TBB with SiteEdit URL  http://<cmsname>>/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/

Comment: That was it Nuno - thanks chaps :)

Comment: Cheers Ram - it's all plain sailing now!

Comment: Can one of you three also write the solution up as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this issue the following steps were taken:

1. Remove the SiteEdit / UI template building block 'Enable inline editing for Page' from the Master Page Template.
2. In the DWT for the content pages (where the layout is just `<contentplaceholder>` tags add the value `<!--SITE_EDIT_INIT-->` inside the final one.
3. Republish everything.

Hope this helps.